# Getting an Exception when loading the plugin manager

Tags: php, joomla

Whenever I try loading the plugin manager, I end up getting this exception.

```
500 Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ebt_extensions` AS a LEFT JOIN ebt_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN ebt_viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access WHERE `type` = 'plugin' AND (a.enabled IN (0, 1)) AND a.state >= 0 AND a.id != 928 Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT a.extension_id , a.name, a.element, a.folder, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.enabled, a.access, a.ordering,uc.name AS editor,ag.title AS access_level FROM `ebt_extensions` AS a LEFT JOIN ebt_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN ebt_viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access WHERE `type` = 'plugin' AND (a.enabled IN (0, 1)) AND a.state >= 0 AND a.id != 928 ORDER BY `folder` asc,a.ordering ASC LIMIT 0, 20 Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ebt_extensions` AS a LEFT JOIN ebt_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN ebt_viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access WHERE `type` = 'plugin' AND (a.enabled IN (0, 1)) AND a.state >= 0 AND a.id != 928
```

I can see in the database the the ebt_extensions table doesn't have an id field (it was replaced with extensions_id). Does anyone know where is the file the executes this query in Joomla?

I'm looking for it but opt to also just post it here in case anyone already knows it.

Comment: What do you mean by `loading the plugin manager,` ? Do you mean after enabling a plugin you are getting this error or while opening the Plugin manager page? Also did you recently installed any plugin?

Comment: No. I didn't install any plugin. This happens whenever I open the plugin manager page. I'm not sure why it's referencing an ID column on the ebt_extension table. It shouldn't since there's no ID column there.

Comment: Did you upgrade your joomla website or this is a fresh installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have recently installed a plugin causing this mess. Go to `phpMyAdmin` and disable the recently installed plugins one by one.

If that doesn't help, then a good idea to override the core Joomla files with a fresh Joomla install (it might be that you have some corruption in one of the files).